# How to resolve the Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.! Always show this whenever i display Map

Tags: react-native, components, location, google-maps-markers, currentlocation

I have two-component classes. First is TrackRoute1.js from which I'm passing bus location parameters and also user current location parameters to class Dispaly.js through the server. But after displaying I keep getting a memory leak that indicates that it **cant perform react state update on an unmounted component**. I tried everything. But it won't help.!

**TrackRoute1.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  FlatList,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  StyleSheet,
} from "react-native";
import AnimatedRegion from "react-native-maps";
import Display1 from "./Display1";
import { LogBox } from "react-native";
import CustomHeader from "../CustomHeader";

LogBox.ignoreLogs(["Setting a timer"]);
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isLoading: true,
      userLat: 0,
      userLng: 0,
      routeCoordinates: [],
      distanceTravelled: 0,
      prevLatLng: {},
      coordinate: new AnimatedRegion({
        userLat: 0,
        userLng: 0,
        latitudeDelta: 0,
        longitudeDelta: 0
      })
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.getCoords(), 1000);
    this._getLocationAsync();

  }

  async getCoords() {
    fetch("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/1323137/feeds.json?results=1")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json.feeds, "API res");
        this.setState({ data: json.feeds });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
      });
  }
  _getLocationAsync = async () => {

 console.log("123")
    let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
    console.log(status)
    if (status !== 'granted') {
      console.log('Permission to access location was denied');
      return;
    }

    // Old method //

    let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
    console.log(location, "my location");
      this.setState({
  userLat: Number(location.coords.latitude),
    userLng: Number(location.coords.longitude)
      })
    console.log(this.state.userLng,"userLng111")


    // New Method //
    // this.location = await Location.watchPositionAsync(
    //   {
    //     enableHighAccuracy: true,
    //     distanceInterval: 1,
    //     timeInterval: 1000
    //   },
    //   newLocation => {
    //     let { coords } = newLocation;
    //     // console.log(coords);
    //     this.setState({
    //       userLat: Number(coords.latitude),
    //         userLng: Number(coords.longitude)
    //           })
    //   },
    //   error => console.log(error)
    // );
    // return this.location;


  };


  
  calcDistance = newLatLng => {
    const { prevLatLng } = this.state;
    return haversine(prevLatLng, newLatLng) || 0;
  };


  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID);

  }

  render() {
    const { data, isLoading } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, width: "100%" }}>
        <CustomHeader title="Track Route" navigation={this.props.navigation} />

        {isLoading ? (
          <ActivityIndicator />
        ) : (
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            keyExtractor={(id, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Display1
                value1={item.field1}
                value2={item.field2}
                value3={item.field3}
                value4={this.state.userLat}
                value5={this.state.userLng}

              />
            )}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  appButtonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: "#fff",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    alignSelf: "center",
    textTransform: "uppercase",
  },
});
```

**Dispaly.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import {
      StyleSheet,
      View,
      Text,
      TouchableOpacity,
      Platform,
      Dimensions,
      Image,
    } from "react-native";
    import * as Location from 'expo-location';
    
    import MapView, {
      PROVIDER_GOOGLE,
      Marker,Polyline,
    
      AnimatedRegion,
    } from "react-native-maps";
    import AutoScrolling from "react-native-auto-scrolling";
    
    import { getPreciseDistance } from 'geolib';
    
    const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");
    export default class Map extends Component {
      // constructor(props) {
      //   super(props);
      //   this.state = {
      //   };
      // }
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
        this.marker = null;
        this.timeout = null;

        this.state = {
          isMapReady: false,
          userLat: 0,
          userLng: 0,
          Time:0,
          Dis: 0,
          hasLocationPermissions: false,
          locationResult: null,
          coordinate: new AnimatedRegion({
            latitude: parseFloat(this.props.value1),
            longitude: parseFloat(this.props.value2),
            latitudeDelta: 0.05,
            longitudeDelta: 0.04,
          }),
        };
      }
      async componentDidMount() {
         this.mounted = true;
   this.timeout = setTimeout(()=>{ var pdis = getPreciseDistance(
          {latitude:parseFloat(this.props.value1), longitude: parseFloat(this.props.value2)},
          {latitude: parseFloat(this.props.value4), longitude: parseFloat(this.props.value5)},
        );
        // console.log(
        //   `Precise Distance\n\n${pdis} Meter\nOR\n${pdis / 1000} KM`
        // );
       this.setState({Dis:pdis,Time:Math.round( pdis/(this.props.value3*1000) )})} ,2000)
    
    
        this.setState({
          Time:this.state.Time.toFixed(2)
        })
      }
      
      componentWillUnmount = () =>{
    this.mounted = false;
    if (this.timeout) {
      clearTimeout(this.timeout)
    }
  }
    
      onMapLayout = () => {
        this.setState({ isMapReady: true });
      };
    
      render() {
    //     console.log( this.state.userLat,
    //  this.state.userLng,"myConsole")
        return (
          <View>
            {this.state.Dis !== 0 ?
              <View style={{backgroundColor:"rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.00006)"}}>
                <Text style={{ color: "green", fontWeight: "bold", marginTop: 10, alignSelf: "center", marginBottom: 3, }}>Bus is {this.state.Dis / 1000} km Away.</Text>
                
                  <AutoScrolling style={{ backgroundColor: "rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.00006)",
        width: 400,
        padding: 10,
        marginBottom: 10,}} endPadding={50}>
              <Text style={ {
        color: "red",
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: "bold",
        textAlign: "center",
        margin: 5,
      }}>Bus is Coming in {this.state.Time} Minutes</Text>
            </AutoScrolling>
    
    </View>
            :null  }
    
            <MapView
            initialRegion={{
              latitude: parseFloat(this.props.value1),
              longitude: parseFloat(this.props.value2),
              latitudeDelta: 0.02,
              longitudeDelta: 0.01,
            }}
            onMapReady={this.onMapLayout}
            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
            loadingIndicatorColor="#e21d1d"
            ref={(map) => (this.map = map)}
            style={{
          width,height
            }}
            loadingEnabled={true}
          >
            {this.state.isMapReady && (
              <MapView.Marker
                key="AIzaSyB8k3Irk81q1k8pbj5tPM33KRWNdtROoOg"
                identifier="marker"
    
                coordinate={{
                  latitude: parseFloat(this.props.value1),
                  longitude: parseFloat(this.props.value2),
                }}
                  flat={false}
                  title="Route 1"
                  description = "Driver: Muhammad Murtaza"
    
              >
              <Image source={require("D:/React Native apps/Bus-Track1-main/assets/car-marker.png")} style={{ width: 60, height: 50 }}/>
    
    
              </MapView.Marker>
            )}
              <MapView.Marker
                key="AIzaSyArnXt8Xqydc3BF9Udt8JCkFuKqgPR_HM0"
                identifier="marker1"
                coordinate={{
                  latitude: parseFloat(this.props.value4),
                  longitude: parseFloat(this.props.value5)
                }}
                            title="My Location"
    
              />
            
           <Polyline
            coordinates={[
        
            
                {   latitude: parseFloat(this.props.value4),
                  longitude: parseFloat(this.props.value5)
                },
                { latitude: parseFloat(this.props.value1),
                  longitude: parseFloat(this.props.value2)
                },
            
            ]}
            strokeColor="red" 
            strokeColors={[
                '#238C23',
                'red'
            ]}
            strokeWidth={5}
        />
            </MapView>
            </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

I have two-component classes. First is TrackRoute1.js from which I'm passing bus location parameters and also user current location parameters to class Dispaly.js through the server. But after displaying I keep getting a memory leak that indicates that it cant perform react state update on an unmounted component. I tried everything. But it won't help.!

[image: Output]